# What is the best, efficient way to index/store code (scripts, queries) for search/retrieval?

Tags: python, indexing

We have a whole lot of code, queries in a whole bunch of folders on a Linux box. Whenever I have to find a script, I do a `fgrep -ircl --include=*.{sql, py, sh} "Keyword" *` .

I am planning on creating a simple search interface (web) which lets you search for a keyword, file type and displays the location of the file and an excerpt from the resulting file. Lucene can be a good candidate I guess but I don't want to create a copy of all my files just for this purpose.

I am planning on indexing the files using a Python script every day at off hours. More like Google desktop I guess but for web (cross-platform availability).

What do you guys suggest is the best way of accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a perl script waaaaay back when to provide a web interface result, still works on my deprecated blackbeltvb.com website if you want to look. It did a live search though, not indexed, and without excerpts.

I also wrote the search for wugnet.com that did ranked results and excerpts, and architected the search that's now in QB Desktop. In your case, I would take that approach - just have a cron job that adds new or updated scripts/files into a database, one big text field, with other fields containing metadata like filenames and types. Then have a web interface into that DB, searching with:

```
select * from data where keyword like '%word%' and keyword (or keyword) etc...
```

There's a FAQ on blackbeltvb.com that shows how to construct a SQL search for ranked keyword results, e.g. "all keywords found", "some found" etc...

Comment: I always argued with my friends against storing complete files in the database cos' I think relational databases aren't designed with that in mind or I may be wrong but I am worried about efficiency. If I go with something like that, then leveraging wordpress' search system with my files makes more sense (minimal effort). What do you say?

Comment: I've used this technique to store very large recordsets - I had one I tested that was more than 500mb as I recall. Doing a text like search on it took about 30 seconds max, with tests that returned about 2,000 rows - and that was using old ADODB stuff. Note that I did NOT use "full text" indexing, rather just a full text search. I've also done this with MySQL and Sybase with the same excellent results. A comparable use case is Wikipedia - very large text articles in very large rowsets searched full text, MySQL. It would be interesting to test against, say, MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python, [Xapian](http://xapian.org/) is the only solution you should consider. It is more "bare metal" than Lucene, but it has **first class** support for the Python bindings to the native C++ implemenation, and is way smaller and faster than Lucene is with real world data sets, by that I mean LARGE data sets.

Comment: I am going through the documentation for Xapian. It looks like it is for indexing web documents (websites). In my case, it is indexing code/queries/scripts in general. I guess some tweaking to index my files but they reside on my dev server and we use a separate server for web server. I have to dive deeper now! Thanks for the link...

Comment: It is a full text indexer, and can index whatever text you tell it too